# How far am I from getting into the "Top 20%" for a particular tag?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, support, rankings, user-rank

I've got a couple of "Top 20%" tags on my careers page.  I'd really like to know how far I am from getting the same award for the "android" tag.  Is there an easy way to get that information?

I don't think the ['android' Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/topusers) page gives me all the information I need.

Comment: It's taken me 24 upvotes to get in the top 30% for [php], and you've got 16 [android] upvotes, so presumably you're not far off from at least getting it onto your CV.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm certainly no T-SQL expert, but perhaps something like [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50880/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag?TagName=android&UserId=112705) is what you're looking for?

According to the query, you were in the top 33% for [android](/questions/tagged/android) at the time of last data load if we exclude all users who have `score <= 0` in answers under that tag. You fare [significantly better](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50886/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag?TagName=android&UserId=112705) if we include those users, so I imagine the real calculation doesn't.

I'm not sure how reliable this approach is, or how closely it represents how Careers makes the determination (they might do it by distribution of total score, for instance, whereas this query does it by ranking; also, they only look at profiles of [people on the Careers site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115650/150235)), but hopefully it's good enough to give you a rough idea.

Comment: Great answer, the results looks correct to me.  It's a shame you missed the bounty by one day or you'd have won it!

Comment: Thanks. Commenting for bookmaking the answer.

Comment: A bit late but I think they calculate the % from everyone with 5+ in a tag (don't quote me on this). Maybe useful to future readers :)

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably to use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).  I spent just a few seconds on this, so it's awful, but perhaps a starting point:

```
select count(*) from (
    select OwnerUserId, sum(Score) as Total from Posts
    where tags like '%android%'
    ​group by OwnerUserId
    having sum(Score) > 8
) as foo
```

(From your profile you currently have a score of 8 in the Android tag.)

It returns 2186 results, and if you remove the HAVING clause it returns 32054.  That would put you in the top 7%, so it's clearly wrong :P.  Top 20% might be based on rep in the tag rather than the score in the tag, or maybe score on answers only, I can't find any info on it, or perhaps my SQL is wrong.  But again, it's just a place to start.

Comment: I wondered if they don't count the people with a score of zero in the 'android' tag, but doing that query yields 14580, which would still mean I am in the top 20%.  As you say, it might be down to rep in that tag.  If somebody could help me with a suitable Data Explorer query that would be great!

Comment: This query only gets questions, because answers don't have their tags field populated.

Comment: @mmyers Yes, it's probably the worst SQL that actually executes that I've ever written :P

Comment: Well, the schema doesn't exactly make this easy. I for one have no idea how I would write a correct query here.