# What possible Top Tags are there in Careers, and how often are they updated?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, data-explorer, top-users

What are the thresholds for the "Top X%" tags on the Careers site, and how often do they update to user profiles?

I can see that "top 30%" and "top 20%" exist on my Career profile, so presumably there are some higher ones?

I've run [this lovely Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/116123/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag?TagName=iphone&UserId=112705) (which answered [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109115/how-far-am-i-from-getting-into-the-top-20-for-a-particular-tag)), and it seems to show I am already in the top 5% for iphone and blackberry on Stackoverflow.  I haven't been active in those tags for at least a couple of months, so I'm wondering if the Careers site hamster needs a kick?

Comment: Ah, the percentage calculation on the query is a bit off for two reasons...let me see if I can fix that.

Comment: Update: I've just got into the top 30% on Android, but it didn't seem to add it to my Careers page until I clicked "edit" and then saved the new tag (even though I already have "Display my top tags & percentiles" checked).

Answer (score 3):

Housecleaning: this was fixed at some point and now you are top 10% for iphone and top 20% for blackberry.  The only divisions are top 30%, top 20% and top 10%.

Comment: The first part of the question ("what possible Top Tags are there in Careers?") wasn't answered yet, as far as I can see. E.g. is it based on popularity on the main site, or is it a curated list?

Comment: It's popularity on Careers, though there are plans (not currently on the schedule) to eventually change it to be popularity on SO.  Tags also have to meet minimum stats (on Careers) to be included so that someone we don't end up making a big deal out of a tag that only shows up once or twice on the site.

Comment: Popularity = tagged in peoples' Likes or Experience sections? Or simply connected to their SO profiles?

Comment: Popularity = http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115753/145077

Comment: @NickLarsen Is there any chance the top tags could pull from *cough* Server Fault as well?