# Top Tags removed from Careers Profiles?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tags, jobs

My profile on careers.stackoverflow.com used to have a part where you could highlight top tags, i.e. it would something like along the lines of **Top % for [TAG]**. That doesn't seem to be showing today however, so has this been removed?

Comment: They seem to be showing up for me in the profile.

Comment: Is there a way to view the same information in stackoverflow itself? I was in the top 10% for the salesforce tag but now it's vanished from my careers profile, I was quite proud of that!

Comment: there's this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/salesforce/topusers I don't know why it vanished from careers for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I do find pages on SO sometimes and then completely fail to find them a second time! Still, in top 5 for all time and top 2 for the month. Bug maybe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The criteria for a tag to be available on Careers 2.0 top percentiles is that it must have at least 500 total answers by users that have at least 2 answers and at least 20 total upvotes in the tag.  The real kicker is that all of these eligible people must also have an account on Careers 2.0.

The reason we rate the tags only against members of Careers 2.0 is that SO has a long tail of people who have answered one question in a tag because the question wasn't really about that, or the question could be answered by someone who is not particularly familiar with that technology.  We try to give the rating not against everyone but only against people who appear to have some actual knowledge about the topic.

Currently the [salesforce](/questions/tagged/salesforce) tag has only 470 eligible answers on Careers.  As soon as it gains the required number of answers, you will likely go from nothing to top 10%.  This exact thing happened to me on the [web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development) tag.  As for this showing up previously and then disappearing, this is likely due to our account merging process which is being updated later this week.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Nick — it had be confused because like I say, I was invited to careers for being in the top 20% for the Salesforce tag, and then moved up to the top 10% shortly after.

Comment: Is there any way to see easily see how many eligible answers are in each tag in the SEDE (or otherwise)?