# Some of the top tags missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, jobs

I am fairly certain that I am in the [top 10% of C++ users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers). However, the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag is not in my list of top 10% on [my Careers CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/klmr).

Is this a bug? How is the percentage calculated? Since C++ is one of the most important skill in my bag, this is pretty relevant for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've listed [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) under the "dislikes" section of your CV, which causes it to be removed from your Top Tags list.

There are [some additional critera](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115624/top-tags-removed-from-careers-profiles/115753#115753) that determines whether or not a tag is shown, but both you and the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag itself should easily meet those. While the fact that you have [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in your "likes" as well should perhaps void the dislike filter, the easiest fix is to just remove it from the "dislikes" section.

To avoid confusion on this matter, and to give the user more control, it might be better if there was an indication that this was the default behaviour and if there was an option to disable it, like in the following mock-up:

[image: mock-up of clearer dislikes behaviour]

Comment: "I hate C++, but you should hire me for it anyway because I'm so masochistic like that."

Comment: The heuristic is unfortunate (and I don’t quite see the sense of it). Of course the CV could live without making that statement but I think C++ really does belong in my dislikes and I like stating that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The most apparent case that would benefit from this that comes to mind is [tag:jquery] versus [tag:javascript], where someone proficient in JavaScript may not want solicitations related to jQuery (where their association with jQuery is just a side-effect of the prevalence of the library). Despite that though, it would certainly be more flexible if you were left with the choice of whether or not that filter should be applied.