# Why doesn't my profile on Careers 2.0 not show my progress in the Kinect tag?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, tags, jobs

My [Careers 2.0 profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/williamfmcinroy) shows that I am in the 30% for the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, but for the [kinect](/questions/tagged/kinect) I am the [highest answer-er](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kinect/topusers). I also have more up-votes and answers in the [kinect](/questions/tagged/kinect) tag. Why does my profile not show this? Do there need to be a certain number of questions in a tag to justify showing it on Careers? Can this be shown for tags with 500+ questions since that means it is an important tag? Currently the [kinect](/questions/tagged/kinect) tag has 594 questions all time.

Comment: [tag:kinect] probably doesn't fulfill [all of the criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115624/top-tags-removed-from-careers-profiles/115753#115753) for being displayed, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @TimStone Hmmmm... How can I tell how many eligible answers there are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the kicker that the counts listed in the other answer are required of users on Careers.  So as soon as users on Careers have 500 answers total, etc, it will just show up all of a sudden.

We don't publicize how close specific tags are to being included in all of Careers, but that seems like a good feature request if someone were to make it...  I'm sure that query is lying around here somewhere.

In the meantime, I suggest adding it to your likes section.

Comment: Ah thanks, I will accept in 2 minutes

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143383/page-to-tell-how-close-tags-are-to-being-posted-on-careers :)