# Page to tell how close tags are to being posted on Careers

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs

Is it possible to have a page where users can see how close tags are to being added to Careers? This is based off of [Why doesn't my profile on Careers 2.0 not show my progress in the Kinect tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143378/why-doesnt-my-profile-on-careers-2-0-not-show-my-progress-in-the-kinect-tag) and [Top Tags removed from Careers Profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115624/top-tags-removed-from-careers-profiles) as neither me or Lacey knew how close the tags were to being posted on our profiles.

Comment: Please, pretty please, with knobs on?