# Thresholds for top tags in Careers too high: introduce vote for exceptions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, jobs, top-users

I'm active in one of the major programming languages in engineering: ***Matlab*** and its important toolbox ***Simulink***. Like other tags, which are not directly involved in software development, e.g. ***R*** and ***LabView***, they are clearly underrepresented here on SO. Basically because SO is not that known amongst engineers, physicists, etc. - but they are of significant importance for their respective fields.

While I really don't care that in tags like ***C++*** even beginners can earn 10k+ reputation in a fairly short time, and in ***Matlab*** just a handful of all-time top users can ever achieve that, it bothers me that I'm not able to share my experience in small tags on Careers 2.0.

[I understood what are the requirements for a tag to get the ability to be a **top tag**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115624/top-tags-removed-from-careers-profiles), and yes ***Matlab*** fulfills the requirements. But ***Simulink*** does not, though it is very important for future employers.

---

So for my opinion there should be exceptions. **One should be able to vote for, let's call them *major language tags*, not to follow the rules linked above.** On the other hand it should be possible to vote for exclusions of meaningless tags like ***matrix***, I would be able to include.

---

Actually there shouldn't be restrictions at all, as like for a real CV everybody should be able to decide for themselves, what tags he wants to show. And if anybody wants to state that they are in the "Top 10% of ***plot***", making the employer asking themselves: "What does he want to tell me with that, is he a printer?" - it should be their choice.

Comment: +1. Not sure if I like the voting mechanism. I think the bigger issue is Careers is somewhat in beta and aimed at non-engineering programmers (web developers, application developers, etc.) right now. I imagine SE has aspirations to expand it to engineers and scientists, but it's of course up to their management to figure out when that makes sense.

Comment: It's true that just a very few engineering companies are at Careers, actually not even one of my desired future employers has a profile. But I think, it will come and then it would be nice to be one of the first in focus.

Comment: Would it be germane for me to edit it to say "is too damn high"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the idea of voting (or community moderation of any type for tags on Careers) we're going to deny the request.  That being said, we had a lot of good conversation about this.

We've had it in mind to eventually allow all tags in the top %, and we're also going to score you against the SO universe, not just people on Careers.  A bit of history here as to why we were using only Careers participants is fairly simple, when this feature went live we were still only sending invitations to users with substantially higher rep requirements than we are today.  Everyone was top 10% in 10-20 tags.  It made the feature kind of worthless because it looked like no one stood out.  At that time we had ~25k Careers profiles total, and today we have over 125k *searchable* profiles.  This change will be coming in the next few weeks.

In the meantime, I'd encourage you to put the Simulink tag on your likes, projects and work experience sections as applicable to make yourself searchable by that technology.