# How to see how many eligible answers for a top tag on the Careers page?

Tags: support, jobs, data-explorer

I only spotted the Top Tags feature of [Stack Overflow careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) the other week and wondered why I didn't have anything to represent my time spent in a [pretty small tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/talend) on Stack Overflow where I'm currently the top user.

Thankfully [someone already asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115624/260268) a question that explained why they weren't seeing a Top Tag on their page - there are certain criteria around when a tag would be displayed on the careers page.

As NickLarsen [explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115753/260268), a tag must have 500 total answers by users that have at least 2 answers and at least 20 total upvotes in the tag.

Is there any way to see how far into that criteria any tag is? I've had a few attempts at writing queries in the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) but I'm completely at a loss for how to approach this or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't 100% answer your question because AFAIK you can't find in SEDE if users have a Careers account. If you leave that out of the equation I believe [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/221345/eligible-answers-for-a-top-tag-on-the-careers-page?uid=2291321) might give you an idea how far your highest scoring tag is doing overall.

It wasn't clear if only answers count for scoring upvotes but that is how I interpreted it.

```
-- uid:Your user id 

with relevanttags as (
select t.id
, sum(a.score) as score
from posts p 
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
inner join posts a on a.parentid = p.id
-- this is not 100% right because 
-- a user could answer the same question twice
where p.answercount > 2 -- at least two answers 
group by t.id
),
alltags as (
select t.id
, count(*) as cnt
from posts p 
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where p.answercount > 2 -- at least two answers 
group by t.id
),
usertags as (
  select t.id
  , sum(a.score) as [yourscore]
  from posts p 
  inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
  inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
  inner join posts a on a.parentid = p.id
  where a.owneruserid = ##uid:Int##
  group by t.id
)
select t.tagname, 
       at.cnt, 
       rt.score as [Answer Score], 
       ut.yourscore as [Your Score]
from relevanttags rt
inner join usertags ut on rt.id = ut.id
inner join alltags at on at.id = ut.id
inner join tags t on t.id = rt.id
order by ut.yourscore desc
```

Your highest scoring tag matching the Careers criteria look like this:

```
tagname | cnt | Answer Score | Your Score
--------+-----+--------------+------------
talend  |  31 |         133  |       59
```

Comment: Very impressed. Thank you very much. I guess I need to spend more time digging around the SEDE to see what can be done there.