# How often do percentage calculations in the careers site get updated?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, jobs

I realize this is not a novel question, but I'm assuming that the answer changes over time.

How often does the careers site get updated with new percentiles for a particular tag? I'm thinking mine might be lagging because I've been pretty active lately, with no noticeable change.

Also, I've noted that, in other questions, it was reported a few months ago that things were in flux, and reputation updates were soon to become more regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careers is updated daily for percentiles and reputation for all your tags.  At the time of writing your rep on careers is 5 points out of date because you got an upvote today.  Percentiles are based on your all time answer score and we only give you the option to show them if you're above the 30th percentile.

According to today's numbers, you're 29 upvotes away from making the 10th percentile in the java tag (assuming no one else answered any java questions in the meantime).

All your other tags are somewhere below the 30th percentile, but they aren't far.

Comment: wow : how did you do this calculation... (that is, how do you calculate the distance from a given percentile)...

Comment: @jay take it with a grain of salt, it's a moving target

Comment: @jay: We calculate the boundaries of the 10th, 20th and 30th percentiles once a day and just check if your answer score for the tag is between the bounds for your profile, so that's how I knew how far away you were.  But Nick is right, it's a moving target.

Comment: @JasonPunyon I know this is not the best place for this, but is there a way for a user to figure out their percentile for a given tag? I'm trying to get top X% for XSS, and I try to answer every question, but I have no idea if I am making meaningful progress towards that goal.

Answer (score 5):

Reputation and tags are updated roughly every 24 hours.  Your current SO reputation is only 5 points ahead of the number listed on Careers 2.0 right now, so I'd guess the update happened recently.  I also noticed that a fair portion of your upvotes (in the Java tag in particular) come from your questions, which are not counted toward your top tag percentages.

As for the speed at which your percentage changes, we only count people on Careers in the pool, not the entire SO population.  That being said, getting to the top 30% in any tag is not particularly difficult, but the cliff gets pretty steep above that.