# top x% in [tag] : rules for the tag to be taken into account?

Tags: support, jobs

In the Careers CV, there is a zone with one or more "top x% for [tag]". 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q9Jz.jpg]

What are the conditions / rules for a tag to appears in this zone? While I answer quite a lot in the abap and sap tags in SO, I gave only a few answers in java. However, only the java tag appears (and I'm pretty sure that I would be better placed in the top % of abap than in java).

I could not find the rules, or how I can find the same info on my profile.
I also checked that I did not ask the top% *not* to be displayed for these tags. This is not the case. The tag simply doesn't appear.

Comment: They've [provided some information about this before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115650/how-often-do-percentage-calculations-in-the-careers-site-get-updated), but I'm not sure why you wouldn't be falling above the 30th percentile anyway - unless perhaps there's so few Careers users with those tags that the percentiles are extremely skewed. You're the [third-highest answerer](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sap/topusers) in [tag:sap] though, so that doesn't seem too likely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There needs to be at least 500 votes for a tag *from people on Careers*.  If you visit the [tags page on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and search for [sap](/questions/tagged/sap), you will see there are only 470ish votes total for the tag, and likely not all of those votes are on Careers.

Comment: i think it will be a long time before i got this % on my careers CV :( thanks

Comment: Sorry to dredge up an old answer, but where exactly is the vote count you are referring to?