# What does the top % mean on careers?

Tags: support, jobs

Is there a meta for careers? If so, sorry this question should be migrated.

I'd love to know what this truly means. top 10% out of... 4 million users? top 10% out of the 100 that have asked or answered a question with this tag?

[image]

Comment: I'd guess it's based on rep gained with questions/answers with that tag

Comment: This is the Meta for careers, you're in the right place.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121078/152859 :)