# Should we allow a user to vote (in agreement with others) that their question is a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I don't have sufficient rep, but I'd like to accept as a duplicate

[What does the top % mean on careers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193234/what-does-the-top-mean-on-careers)

Should we be able to add a vote to close for duplicate if we asked it, even if the rep is too low.

Comment: You can always use _flagging_.

Comment: Perhaps only if the close votes already exist, otherwise you might get even more noise in the close queue, and we all know it doesn't need that

Comment: If you accept it as a duplicate, there's no real reason for the duplicate to exist, so why not just delete your question?

Comment: @StephenTG Adding open questions to the close vote queue isn't a bad thing.  It's a good thing.  The queue doesn't have problems keeping up with new questions added, it just hasn't succeeded in getting through all of the questions with 1-4 votes from before there was a CV queue.  Also note that users can flag questions for closure if they can't vote, so they can already add posts to that queue easily enough.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough

Comment: Oh, the irony of having your question about duplicates being a duplicate...

Comment: @Johnny Not *just* a duplicate... but a duplicate of a duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a compelling reason to add this.  It's rather uncommon for people to want to close their own questions, so this feature wouldn't be used all that much, and we generally don't have so much of an issue closing questions once the process has started that this feature is desperately needed.

You can always flag for closure if you find a duplicate and there are not yet any votes to close, just to get the process started.