# Data Explorer /q/{id} redirection results in broken URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Something is messed up with the Data Explorer and how it is resolving URLs.

Currently, URLs like this [`http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1928`](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1928) all end up at the Page Not Found page with this as the redirected URL:
[https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/System.Collections.Generic.List%601[System.Int32]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.Int32%5D)

It seems to be related to `/q/[id]` format not getting properly expanded to `/query/[id]`?

In particular, all the links on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer) are broken.

---

After additional investigation, [this URL](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116159/) gives a runtime error.

I found this out when trying to get to the first query linked to in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110718/133750) by replacing the `/q/` with `/query/`.

I'm not sure, but the issues seem to be related. (or possibly errors just are not being handled well.)

Comment: fixed now ... sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect issue was due to a missing `.First()` call that [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) has [now taken care of](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/detail?r=d48f8028a88064e1d413ffd59055333fc38df9bc).

Just replacing the `/q/` with `/query/` isn't how that redirection works, which is why you received an error when you tried to transform the URL manually (the ID you specified is invalid for the new URL form). That should be handled more gracefully than with a server error page though, so I've [put out a change](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=2dad3b37425c094e71106dc6090be426a645e24c) to return the 404 page instead if the ID was invalid. If it gets pulled, you'll see [Edgar F. Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd) instead of the ugly internal error page.