# Can we view tag percentiles?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I know that careers will show tag percentiles of 30 or better. What about outside of careers? What about the entire percentile range? Is there anyway to know what percentile we are in for any given tag?

Comment: Related: [How far am I from getting into the “Top 20%” for a particular tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109115/how-far-am-i-from-getting-into-the-top-20-for-a-particular-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily calculate the percentage yourself from the "top users" page. To get there:

1. Click on the tag anywhere you see it on the site (or do a search).
2. From the [tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) page, click on the "top users" link:

![][1]
3. Find yourself on the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers) page, and compare your score to the other users on the list.

The top answerers and askers are shown, each for the last 30 days and for all time.

If you are not in the top 20, but have a score in that tag, your user card will appear at the bottom of the list, with your metrics. That *does not* mean that you're ranked 21st.

Alternatively, if you're handy with database queries, you can get the answer even more quickly by using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPdig.png